# Spark does not deallocate executors

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark

I'm using pyspark 3.3.2 with kubernetes and trying to play with a simple toy setup.
The relevant part of configuration is:

```
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true
spark.dynamicAllocation.shuffleTracking.enabled=true
spark.dynamicAllocation.executorIdleTimeout=30s
spark.dynamicAllocation.cachedExecutorIdleTimeout=40s
spark.executor.instances=0
spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=0
spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=50
spark.cleaner.periodicGC.interval=30s
spark.master=k8s://https://<...>:6443
```

Next, I'm running simple code:

```py
instances = 50
df = spark.createDataFrame([{"a": i} for i in range(instances * 3)])
df = df.repartition(instances)

@F.udf()
def udf():
    time.sleep(random.randint(2, 10))
    return random.randint(1, 42)

print(df.withColumn('random', udf()).agg(F.sum('random').alias('sum')).collect()[0].sum)
time.sleep(999) # executors never get removed
```

This leads to creating up to 50 executors and running the tasks. However after the job is complete, no executors get actually removed no matter how long I wait.
This does not look like intended behavior to me, or have I missed some other required option here?

Also wanted to note that if running this code:

```py
df = spark.read.parquet("s3a://<directory with 1TB of parquet files>")
print(df.count())
time.sleep(999) # this is fine, all executors get removed within 20-30s after stage end
```

the behavior is intended and all executors get quickly removed.

Comment: What will happen if you try to apply your `udf` to a dataframe `df = spark.read.parquet(...`? Do executors exit?

Comment: @mazaneicha In such scenario executors are removed very quickly. But there a no shuffles being generated at all. If I then add `df = df.repartition(100)` right after reading parquets, the problems pops up again - executors get never removed.
Note that in my second example with `df.count()` there *are* shuffle blocks being generated too, but for some reason they get successfully removed (I believe when periodicGC comes in), and then executor allocation manager sees they don't contain anything preventing them from deallocation and removes them.